# attempt to insert section 9223372036854775807 UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a collectionView which tries to implement infinite horizontal scrolling.
The idea is that after a certain offset.x, I insert new items in `performBatchUpdates` and this is how I get my new cells.

I get the following exception inserting an array on indexPaths:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert section 9223372036854775807 but there are only 1 sections after the update'

Here is the code when I add the indexPaths:

```
func scrollRight() {
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath()]
    for i in 0..<7 {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
    }
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        numberOfItems += 7
        collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        for i in 0..<7 {
            days[i] -= 7
        }
    }, completion: nil)
    indexPaths.removeAll()
    for i in 7..<14 {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
    }
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        numberOfItems -= 7
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

That is triggered in ScrollViewDidEndDragging,
any ideas why would it do that? There is only one section; also I update my dataSource for the `numberOfItemsInSection` before I get the indices inserted. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't update collection view directly, but instead update your datamodel (add more items) when you scroll to the right, then reload your collection view.

Comment: that works, thanks, maybe you know what is the best approach to get a horizontal infinite scrolling collectionView? because with that approach i cannot add items when i scroll to the left, and it's also need. if you want post your comment as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298091/infinitely-scrolling-in-both-directions-of-uicollectionview-with-sections